# How to open or convert .GPK (audio) files?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, file-format

I wondering how I could open `.gpk` files? These files were created by my DigiTech JamMan Loopstation. Internet says WaveLab, but this is not available for Ubuntu, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that wavelab is only avaiable on Windows and MAC. You could try to use wine or a virtual machine with windows on it. I've found no other application that opens/converts this type of files.